# Java DecimalFormat returns a "?"

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

My `DecimalFormat` is sometimes returning a '?' when trying to `format()`. Is there an input that would create this scenario?

For example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
df.format(X); // output : '?'
```

What could `X` possibly be?

Comment: What is X, how is it declared, and how defined?

Comment: Could you give us a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: My question should've been phrased better, but was looking to answer the generic question "In what cases will a DecimalFormat return a '?' when format()'ing

Comment: cleaned up my question, thanks guys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not a question mark, it's a `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which is displayed as ? since it can't be mapped to the output encoding:

> NaN is formatted as a string, which typically has a single character \uFFFD. This string is determined by the DecimalFormatSymbols object. This is the only value for which the prefixes and suffixes are not used.

Similarly, ? in representation of infinity is a `U+221E INFINITY` character (∞).

> Infinity is formatted as a string, which typically has a single character \u221E, with the positive or negative prefixes and suffixes applied. The infinity string is determined by the DecimalFormatSymbols object.

**See also:**

- [`DecimalFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: FWIW, Looks like this changed in one of the newer JDKs.  I'm now getting "NaN" for NaN instead \uFFFD

Answer (score 5):

It'll return "?" if `X` is `Float.NaN` or `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY`. It appears that `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` returns "-?".

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved very similar problem. In my case I was trying to return currency sign to Spring and display it in Thymeleaf template.

```
public String getAmountDue() {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("¤0.00");
    decimalFormat.setCurrency(this.currency);
    String result = decimalFormat.format(amountDue);
    return result;
}
```

So this was actually returning correctly formatted String but in the browser instead of, e.g. `€99.99` I was getting `?99.99` - so instead of currency sign there was question mark displayed.

In the end, that was a problem with my Spring configuration, that I solved by adding `characterEncoding` to my configuration:

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
  ...
  <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have to define local instance over here..like I get Locale.ENGLISH

Double no=20.2563;

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    df.applyPattern("##.00");

    String output = df.format(no);
```